# How I can modify my iis webserver of azure. I want to edit Webpage Title: my studentID’s Windows Server and I also want to edit body text of iis it

Tags: azure, iis

I installed iis webserver on windows but I want to modify its title and add some body text int.How to do that.

Web title to my name
and add some body text in it

Comment: To get started with IIS, you need to buy a book or use Microsoft documentation like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis to understand where the actual web pages are. Then you can edit them as you wished in any code editor.

Comment: If you need to add something, please edit your question instead of my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start IIS Manager, right-click on the website and select "Explore" to access the physical path of the website. Find the webpage you need to modify and modify it in the code editor.

[image]